# UDP not big enough for my message, how to improve?

Tags: udp, ar.drone

i am writing my programming for ar drone using UDP, but the drone sometimes hangs, i think maybe the UDP is not big enough, is there any way to improve the situation if still using UDP?

Comment: Using UDP seems like real wrong choice here.

Answer (score 0):

UDP datagram sizes are limited by:

1. The outgoing socket send buffer. Defaults for this vary wildly, from 8k in Windows to 53k or more in other systems.
2. The Path MTU or Maximum Transmission Unit of the entire network path between you and the receiver. This is typically no more than 1260 bytes.

The safest size for a UDP datagram is 534 bytes as this will never be fragmented by the transport. If you're planning on sending datagrams larger than this you need to consider a different transport, usually TCP.